# OpenERP Report Designer fails to Send To Server

Tags: report, odoo, openoffice.org

I'm stuck on a quirky issue with OpenERP Report Designer where after clicking on 'Send Report to Server' in OpenOffice for Windows, the Sent To Server window stays open and nothing happens This occurs wether I choose to 'Open a new report' or 'Modify Existing Report'. After any editing, I can't get a report to save back to the server.

If I don't type anything on an existing report page, it will process, and I see a verification in the log that there was a login. I've tried reinstalling the module and the zip file to no avail.

Please help me to use this simple yet powerful tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working with LibreOffice Writer,

- Open Libreoffice Writer
- OpenERP Report Designer/Server Parameters
- Add server, port and Protocol Connection = "XML-RPC" after do this it will ask for Server Connection Parameter, Choose your db,login and password
- OpenERP Report Designer/Open a New Report and Start draw your report.

Hope this will help you

Comment: Please use list, so that this will be easy to read and understand

Comment: thnx for your kind suggestion it will help for next time :-)

Comment: Thanx, but I moved on from this reporting system.